Shortest path in Directed Acyclic Graph. Is topological Sort Really needed?
Here's a famous problem:
Given a Directed Acyclic Graph of N vertices from 0 to N-1 and a 2D Integer array(or vector) edges[ ][ ] of length M, where there is a directed edge from edge[i][0] to edge[i][1] with a distance of edge[i][2] for all i.
Find the shortest path from src(0) vertex to all the vertices and if it is impossible to reach any vertex, then return -1 for that vertex.
Here's how I solve using dfs. I take each of the node and pass through the dfs function and keep updating the the target Node distance in dis array. And I see this works fine for a couple of test cases.


const edge = [[0,1,2],[0,4,1],[4,5,4],[4,2,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,6],[5,3,1]];
const N = 6, M = 7;

let graph = {}, dis = [];

for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
    graph[i] = [];
    dis[i] = Infinity; // Intitalize each of the node's distance to Infinity.
}

// Create adjacency list

for(let vertex of edge){
    var [node, child, distance] = vertex;
    graph[node].push([child, distance]);
}

const dfs = function(graph, node, targetNode){
    if(node === targetNode) return 0;
   
   let minDistance = Infinity;
    
    for(let k of graph[node]){
        const [el, distance] = k;
        minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, distance+dfs(graph, el, targetNode))
    }
    
    return minDistance;
}

for(var i=0; i<N; i++){
    dis[i] = dfs(graph, 0, i); //call the dfs with each of the node as target and 0 being the source
}

console.log(dis);



Now the solutions that I see almost always use topological sort and I'm pretty sure, there could be some good reason for that. So my question is, is that so or the above program is just fine. I'm unable to test this for all test cases because the platform I refer to for this problem only has java and c++ support.

Do you have a link to the problem? In any case, in general, you can just apply Dijkstra's algorithm.

@Unmitigated Yeah here it is: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/shortest-path-in-undirected-graph/1?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=collab_striver_ytdescription&utm_campaign=shortest-path-in-undirected-graph

Okay, I can see why many solutions use topological sort. Note that the problem states "Expected Time Complexity: O(N+M)". Your solution is way too slow.

@Unmitigated I see. So slowness is the only reason or the code I wrote is incorrect too for any of the cases? That was the first approach that came to me mind which I thought was straightforward.

Your solution is not incorrect, but it is very inefficient to run a DFS for every single node to get all distances from the source. You could've just run Dijkstra's.

@Unmitigated I see. Thank you.

@Unmitigated Topological sort is faster than Dijkstra's

@MattTimmermans I am aware. I just mentioned that as a standard solution that could be more generally applied.
